# asp.net mvc, how to pass actionlink parameter from form element

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is it possible to pass the value of a form element somewhere on the page, to an actionlink as a parameter? eg.

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyList")

@Html.ActionLink("FooText", "FooMethod", "FooController", dropdownvaluehere)
```

where in the FooController class

```
public ActionResult FooMethod(int retrieveddropdownvalue)
{
    //do something with retrieved value
}
```

Comment: Since the value is selected on the client, you need to construct the link using javascript/jquery

Comment: why not use a form to submit the information to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Javascript/Jquery instead:

```
<a onclick = "myfunction()"> FooText </a>
```

in your script:

```
function myfunction()
{
    window.location = '@URL.Action("FooMethod", "FooController")?parameter=' + (get selected value from dropdown);
}
```